# how to know which statement the running process is executing

Tags: c++, c, process

I have a process which suddenly hanged and is not giving any core dump and is also not killed.i can see it still running using the ps command.

how can i know which statement it is currently executing inside the code.

basically i want to know where exactly it got hanged.

language is c++ and platform is solaris unix.

```
demos.283> cat test3.cc
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{

sleep(100);
return 0;

}
demos.284> CC test3.cc 
demos.285> ./a.out &
[1] 2231
demos.286> ps -o "pid,wchan,comm"
  PID            WCHAN COMMAND
23420 fffffe86e9a5aff6 -tcsh
 2345                - ps
 2231 ffffffffb8ca3376 ./a.out
demos.290> ps
   PID TTY         TIME CMD
  3823 pts/36      0:00 ps
 23420 pts/36      0:00 tcsh
  3822 pts/36      0:00 a.out
demos.291> pstack 3822
3822:   ./a.out
 fed1a215 nanosleep (80478c0, 80478c8)
 080508ff main     (1, 8047920, 8047928, fed93ec0) + f
 0805085d _start   (1, 8047a4c, 0, 8047a54, 8047a67, 8047c05) + 7d
demos.292>
```

Comment: Attach your debugger to the process and start debugging.

Comment: as it is happening in production environment i cannot run a debugger over there.also the behaviour is not reproduced everywhere but only in production and that too not regularly

Comment: Maybe you can estimate location by using strace style tool. Solaris seems to have truss and DTrace tools that are similar with strace of Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with ***pstack*** passing pid as parameter. You can use ***ps*** to get the process id (pid)

For example: ***pstack 1267***

Answer (score 7):

You have several options: the easiest is to check the `WCHAN` wait channel that the process is sleeping on:

```
$ ps -o "pid,wchan,comm"
  PID WCHAN  COMMAND
 2350 wait   bash
20639 hrtime i3status
20640 poll_s dzen2
28821 -      ps
```

This can give you a good indication of what the process is doing and is very easy to get.

You can use `ktruss` and `ktrace` or `DTrace` to trace your process. (Sorry, no Solaris here, so no examples.)

You can also attach `gdb(1)` to your process:

```
# gdb -p 20640
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2
...
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fd1a99fd123 in __select_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#1  0x0000000000405533 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fd1a993deff in __libc_start_main (main=0x4043e3, argc=13, ubp_av=0x7fff25e7b478, 
...
```

The backtrace is often the single most useful error report you can get from a process, so it is worth installing `gdb(1)` if it isn't already installed. `gdb(1)` can do a *lot* more than just show you backtraces, but a full tutorial is well outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Kenneth: I've never ceased to be amazed at what the machine will tell you, if only you know the right incantations to ask. :)

Comment: Please see my edit.it does not show the actual sleep function..may i know the reason why?

Comment: i have already mention that i cannot run gdb in that environment.I know that the trace from gdb would be very useful